# Как заменить строку на другую строку по данным словаря?

Tags: python, словари, замена, нечеткий-поиск

у меня есть строка

> 0 трубок использовали для прожигания стальковша Тликв.=1519. Разлита полностью. Плавка с обработкой на УПК. М-11 - 67,0 м./мерная/ замена воронки Vр -0,8 м/мин /7-ой сляб/. В конце плавки не наполнение п.к.Vр -0,8 м/мин 9-й ;10-й слябы/

и есть словарь

- плавка с Аргона // Плавка получена с установки продувки аргоном
- тликв=1231 // Температура ликвидуса = 1231
- 1 трубок использовали для прожигания стальковша // для прожигания шибера стальковша использовано 0 трубок
- разлита полностью // Сталь разлита полностью
- плавка с обработкой на УПК // Плавка обработана на установке «печь-ковш» с возможностью подогрева стали
- 12маш 4м замена воронки // 12 машина 4 метр замена воронки
- слябы переданы в пл1 // стальные слябы переданы в плавильный цех №1
- плавка с обработкой на АЦВ // плавка с обработкой на АЦВ
- на переходе с пл. 1 на пл.2 перековшовка // перековшовка на переходе с 1 плавки на 2

и надо из той строки получить новую с помощью словаря, при этом сохранить все исходные цифры
в строке фразы могут быть в разном порядке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам в словаре необходимо хранить регулярные выражения. Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```py
import re
d = {
r"тликв=(\d+)" : r"Температура ликвидуса = \1",
r"(\d+)маш (\d+)м замена воронки" : r"\1 машина \2 метр замена воронки"
}
```

Выражения, заключенные в `()` образуют группу. `\n` значит подставить n-ую группу на это место, группы нумеруются с 1. Далее прогоняем текст по этим регуляркам:

```py
for key in d: # Проходим по ключам (регуляркам) словаря
    text = re.sub(key, d[key], text) #Проверять, есть ли вхождение регулярки, не обязательно, тк в таком случае просто ничего не заменится.
```

Ссылки по теме:
https://python-scripts.com/import-re-regular-expression
https://habr.com/ru/post/349860/#Ispolzovanie_grupp_pri_zamenah
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: это слишком легко, у меня еще и нечеткий поиск и цифры в середине строки, которые надо сохранить

Comment: Что значит "нечеткий поиск"?

Comment: то что могут быть опечатки в строке, но это не совсем проблема, проблема извлечь цифры из строки и подставить их в строку из словаря

Comment: Понял, что вы хотите. В таком случае использовать регулярные выражения. Сейчас исправлю ответ.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вы мне очень сильно помогли!!!!
А ещё не подскажете как сделать чтобы менялось не только "..15маш 5м..." но и "...15м 5м..."?
то есть некий or. Или просто несколько регулярок в словарь?

Comment: В регулярных выражениях есть "или".  "A|B" соответствует "выражение A или выражение B".

Comment: не смог использовать | , не подскажете ее синтаксис?

Comment: Последний вопрос - как делать не замену в существующей строке а добавлять в новую строку уже преобразованную строку?

Comment: Я Вам уже дал синтаксис `|`. Вот пример для `"..15маш 5м..." но и "...15м 5м..."`: `re.sub(r"(\d+)(?:маш|м) (\d+)м", r"\1 машина \2 метр", text)`. `(?:...)` значит искать группу, но не выделять её (используется, если Вы далее не хотите где-то эту группу использовать).

Comment: Второй вопрос не понимаю. Приведите пример.